# Input and div alignment

Tags: html, css-position

I would like to align a checkbox and a spinner I created

```html
    <input type="checkbox"/>Item name 
    <span>Description</span>                                     
    <div id="spinner-container">
         <input id="inner-spinner"/>
         <div class="nav">
             <div class="up">+</div>
             <div class="down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

How can I make spinner-container stay beside the Description in the span tag?

Comment: Did you try making <style>#spinner-container{clear:none;float:left} </style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#spinner-container #inner-spinner{
height:30px;
}
.nav{
display:inline-block;
position: relative;

}
.nav > .up ,.down{
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
width:20px;
border:solid 1px #A9A9A9;
left:-5px;
color:#fff;
height:16px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.nav >.up{
top:-22px;
background-color:green;

}
.nav >.down{
top:-4px;
background-color:red;

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>Item name 
    <span>Description</span>                                     
    <div id="spinner-container">
         <input id="inner-spinner"/>
         <div class="nav">
             <div class="up">+</div>
             <div class="down">-</div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the div's display to 'inline-block'

```
#spinner-container{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Might aswell have to adjust the vertical-align and margins. But that depends.